# glReadPixels vs. glGetTexImage

Tags: opengl

I need to extract a smallish rectangle (200x200) from a large texture (2048x2048), and put the RGBA pixels in memory. There seems to be two ways to do this:

a) use glGetTexImage and pass in the buffer which receives the whole texture, and read the appropriate pixels from that

b) create a framebuffer, draw into it using the texture with only the portion needed, and extract the pixels produced with glReadPixels.

I'm guessing b) is faster, but I am relative novice, I'd like to know whether I'm heading in the right direction. a) is easier to code so I wonder whether the possible speed hit is negligible.

Steve

Answer (score 10):

Given that the image data is in a texture, there are several possible solutions. Ordered from most desired to least:

- Employ `glGetTextureSubImage` (requires OpenGL 4.5 or ARB_get_texture_sub_image) to just do the job directly.
- Use `glCopyImageSubData` (requires OpenGL 4.3 or ARB_copy_image. Or NV_copy_image. The latter is [implemented on more hardware than just NVIDIAs](http://opengl.gpuinfo.org/gl_listreports.php?listreportsbyextension=GL_NV_copy_image)) to [copy the desired rectangle](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture_Storage#Texture_copy) into a texture of the appropriate size, then use `glGetTexImage`on that.
- Attach the large texture to an FBO, then attach the small texture to another FBO. Use `glBlitFramebuffer` (requires OpenGL 3.0 or ARB_framebuffer_objects) [to copy the desired section of the large texture to the small one](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer#Blitting). Then use `glGetTexImage` on the small texture.

Rendering the texture to a framebuffer with triangles would only be needed in the event of working under very old OpenGL implementations.

Comment: Whoops, for a) I meant glGetTexImage not glTexImage2d.

Comment: OK I coded up solution b) and it's a whopping 50 times faster (100 microseconds compared to 5 milliseconds.) Hindsight is 20/20.

Comment: @stevenkucera: I've updated my answer to match your corrected question.

Comment: Alright I tried glGetTextureSubImage and for the record it takes around a mere 25 microseconds.